# How to save custom objects to Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello Everyone I have a quick question. I'm trying to save a custom model to Firestore like so:

```
import Firebase

    let city = City(name: "Los Angeles",
                    state: "CA",
                    country: "USA",
                    isCapital: false,
                    population: 5000000)
    do {
        try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
    }
```

The issue is .setData(from: city)   is not working? Its saying Extraneous argument label 'from:' and when I do I get an error. Did Firestore deprecate this or do I have to import something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The documentation isn't exactly wrong on this, it' just incomplete in one section. Firebase added an extension to make crafting custom obects easier but didn't mention that extension in the documentation. (I assume its an extension)

The documentation on [Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) is an example of the code that needs the extension

Simple fix by adding this to your podfile

```
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

and then do a pod update either in terminal or cocoapods.

Then in your Class just update the imports to include that

```
import Cocoa
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

For reference the code in the docs was this

```
try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
```

and this

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA")

 docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    let result = Result {
    try document.flatMap {
       try $0.data(as: City.self)
    }
 }
```

and this line

```
.data(as: City.self)
```

and

```
.setData(from:
```

were the 'troublemakers' that needed the FirebaseFirestoreSwift